# Create Template Library File

Tags: c++, templates

I've created a library, based on templates. I want to provide a file that a user of my library could just include. Because its a template library, I think the library file needs to be a .h file. So to create I included all my other template header files (with the declarations and definitions) and then compiled with g++ -E (just preprocess). The idea worked until somebody who uses the library uses a standard header (like string) or library (like boost) I've used in my library, too. Because of the preprocessing all the definitions in i.e. String got copied into the library file. If the user uses i.e. String too, the compiler throws an double definition error, because its defined in my library and in the header.

So how can I solve my problem? Is there another way of generating my library file? Or can I prevent the inclusion of the headers and just insert a include statement for everything else than my own files, which are processed at the users compiling?

Thank you
DevWurm

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense at all. You don't preprocess a header in attempts to make it stand-alone. You code the header to be standard conforming and let the client (the user-code) provide a conforming implementation your library consumes. Your template header *is* your library file. Removing dependencies by piping through a preprocessor will result in both platform-dependent code and a slew of other issues, Is there some particular reason you're *not* encapsulating your template library in a *namespace*?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes I see...so should I provide a whole folder with all the sources and a library file instead of only one library fuel like I thought of? Why do you think I'm not encapsulating it into a namespace? I do so?

Comment: if you have multiple user-defined headers then they should be part of your distro. How you set that up is up to you, but I would probably keep them in a `yourlibname` folder, making sure the client includes the folder *where **that** folder* is located in their include path, *and* code *your* headers *and theirs* to `#include "yourlibname/header.h"` That may be a little overt for what you're trying to do, but I'm not privy to your library structure; you are. It is a setup similar to how `boost` is laid out. But I can tell you trying to preprocess a solution is *not* the correct path to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing the preprocessing; you should leave that up to the machine of the end-user when they compile with your headers. All of the preprocessor work will match YOUR system if you do it, which will break, e.g. system specific preprocessing (`#if defined (__APPLE__)`) or limits (32 bit `int`). It should also be up to them to have a copy of the standard library, and they might want a different implementation of it than you have. It also reduces code bloat. Take a look at this snippet of the [boost CRC header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/crc.hpp) for example, which provides a templated CRC function:

```
#ifndef BOOST_CRC_HPP
#define BOOST_CRC_HPP

#include <boost/config.hpp>   // for BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT, etc.
#include <boost/integer.hpp>  // for boost::uint_t

#include <climits>  // for CHAR_BIT, etc.
#include <cstddef>  // for std::size_t

#include <boost/limits.hpp>  // for std::numeric_limits
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense. My problem is, that I've splitted up my library in many files to keep the survay. So now I need something to create one single file with all my code, that the user of my lib can use. Can you suppose on method of achieving that, without copying everything in one file manually? Or is it common to provide a whole folder with files and tell the user to include one file, which is in the folder, where all the include statements are written in?

Comment: Usually, you'll provide give them a folder with all of the headers you need, and one or two "master" headers to include that will include all the other needed headers.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a very constructive answer :)